# Remove numbers from all files in a folder

Tags: powershell, batch-file, ssis

I have a folder with a load of files with a random number in the middle. they are in this format:

```
Input-4535344534x-results.xml
Input-4535344534y-log.xml
Input-4535344534z-main.xml
```

Is there any way to remove the numbers through a .bat file or something I can execute as part of an ssis package so that I am left with:

```
Input-x-results.xml
Input-y-log.xml
Input-z-main.xml
```

I tried running this in powershell but it does not seem to work

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.xml | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '^[0-9_]+'}
```

Thanks

Comment: Remove `^` from the regexp, it anchored the numbers to the first character.

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B *.xml') do for /F "tokens=1* delims=0123456789" %%b in ("%%a") do ren "%%a" "%%b%%c"`

Comment: What if you have 2 files: one is `Input-4535344534x-results.xml` and the other is `Input-3424233423x-results.xml`. They are in the same folder and they will be renamed to the same name -> the rename will fail. You need to think of this situation as well.

Comment: Yes rory83, you need to think about the situation described by @It-Z and if it apply to your problem, modify the question and add this _new requirement_ (in such a case, I will generate a _new solution_).

Answer (score 0):

```
ls Input-*.xml -n | % { mv $_ ($_ -replace '\d+') }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an [explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/305455) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.xml | 
Foreach-Object {
    $newName = $_.Name -replace "(\w+-)(\d+)(\w+)",'$1$3'
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newName
}
```

**UPDATE:** Simplifying

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.xml | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace "(\w+-)(\d+)(\w+)",'$1$3'}
```

Let me know if this helps.